# How to return the list values from this haskell snippet

Tags: haskell

I know it is verbose but that is how I am learning the syntax.  With this line at

(abCombo' a 2 lst) ... I want to return the 'list' and/or print the list but I am having trouble extracting the list with this return type, ' Writer [String] [Int]'.

```
-- Loop through several integer values
-- and calculate the power of a^b, append to list
abCombo' :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Writer [String] [Int]
abCombo' a b lst
    | b == maxB = do
        tell [ "  ... x-Done(1): a^b = " ++ show (a^b) ++ " // " ++ show lst  ]
        return ((a^b):lst)
    | otherwise = do
        tell [ "  ... x-Processing: a^b = " ++ show (a^b) ++ " // " ++ show lst ]
        abCombo' a (b+1) ((a^b):lst)

-- Loop through several integer values
-- and calculate the power of a^b, append to list
abCombo :: Int -> [Int] -> Writer [String] [Int]
abCombo a lst
    | a == maxA = do              
        tell [ "- Done(2): a=" ++ show a ]
        abCombo' a 2 lst
    | otherwise = do
        (abCombo' a 2 lst) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line of interest, here
        tell ["- Processing: a=" ++ show a]
        abCombo (a + 1) lst
```

...

That is the current code above, I want to change it to:

```
abCombo :: Int -> [Int] -> Writer [String] [Int]
abCombo a lst
    | a == maxA = do              
        tell [ "- Done(2): a=" ++ show a ]
        abCombo' a 2 lst
    | otherwise = do
        let res = (abCombo' a 2 lst) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line of interest, here            
        tell ["- Processing: a=" ++ show a]
        abCombo (a + 1) (flatten snd res)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you learning Haskell, that you've learned the Writer monad so early?

Comment: Relearning.  But I saw it in the Learn haskell for a better good book.

Comment: Oh, I see. Too bad - I was hoping there was a tutorial out there that taught `Writer` early!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To bind the result of an action in a `do`-block you need to use `<-` instead of `let`.

```
res <- abCombo' a 2 lst      -- res :: [Int]
```

This is because with `let`, you're just putting a name on the action itself.

```
let res = abCombo' a 2 lst   -- res :: Writer [String] [Int]
```

Comment: "Writer [String] [Int]"  If this is the return type, and then I do "res <- abCombo' a 2 lst"  what is in 'res'?

Comment: @BerlinBrown: `res` will be bound to the result of the writer action, which in this case is `[Int]`. In general, when you write `result <- action`, `action` must have type `m a` where `m` is some monad, and `result` will then have the type `a`. In this case, we have `action :: Writer [String] [Int]`. Since type constructor application associates to the left (just like function application), this is equivalent to `(Writer [String]) [Int]`, so we see that `m` must be `Writer [String]` and `a` must be `[Int]`. Or to put it more simply, the result type is the rightmost one.